# Mips - Taking in a user given integer and returning the letter in the alphabet that corresponds to that letter, a ? if its outside the 1 - 26

Tags: mips

I'm trying to take a user given number and then that number should be translated into the alphabet to a certain letter. Ex. 1 = A

```
    .data
Prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the value of n here: "
Prompt2:    .asciiz "The Letter is: "
Prompt3:    .asciiz "?"

.globl main
.text
main:

li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt1
syscall
li  $v0, 5
syscall
blez    $v0, end
li  $t1, 64
add $a0, $t1, $v0
syscall
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt2
syscall
li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $t0
syscall




end:    
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt3
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole bunch of confusion here about the proper arguments of system calls. I suggest reading the documentation [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html).

But, it should be noted that this is actually a really easy problem that shouldn't require loops.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
$a0 = getInt();
printChar('@' + $a0);
```

If you're confused as to why this works, I would suggest taking a look at an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/).

---

The correction of your attempt might be:

```
.data
Prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the value of n here: "
Prompt2:    .asciiz "The Letter is: "
Prompt3:    .asciiz "?\n"

.globl main
.text
main:

#print prompt 1
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt1
syscall

#get N
li  $v0, 5
syscall
blez    $v0, end
move $t8, $v0 #store N in $t8

#print prompt2
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt2
syscall

#print character equivalent
li  $v0, 4
li  $t1, '@'
add $a0, $t1, $t8
li  $v0, 11
syscall

#print ?
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt3
syscall

end:
li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: I changed my code around, but now I don't think I'm grasping the converting of ints to characters

Comment: Right. Edited for you.